# Cannot read Composer package from private hg repository on bitbucket

Tags: mercurial, composer-php, bitbucket

I am trying to use a Composer package from a private Mercurial repository on bitbucket. Composer says it can't find the package.

Let's call the package `my-user/my-private-repo`. For what it's worth, I've added my SSH public key to bitbucket for this repository. The `composer.json` file for the package looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "my-user/my-private-repo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Some Composer Package",
  "author": "me",
  "license": "blah",
  "require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "5.0.*"
  }
}
```

And the `composer.json` for the project in which I want to use that package looks like:

```
{
    "require": {
        "my-user/my-private-repo": "^0.0.1"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type":"package",
            "package":{
                "name":"my-user/my-private-repo",
                "version": "default",
                "source":{
                    "type": "hg",
                    "url":  "bitbucket.org/my-user/my-private-repo",
                    "reference":"default"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

When I run `composer update`, I get the following error:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package my-user/my-private-repo could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

I've read everything I can find on SO that seems relevant, but I can't seem to get past this error. How can I use my Composer package in a project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the "package" type. This is only really useful for software that is NOT inside a repository. It is meant as a replacement to integrate ZIP downloads into Composer.

Additionally, it is complicated to collect all necessary info for that "package" type.

Repositories are way easier:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url":  "ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/my-user/my-private-repo"
    }
]
```

The repository must have a valid `composer.json` file - and it really helps if it also has tagged versions, because dependencies using branches will break eventually because you cannot signal backward incompatible changes and cannot go back to a defined earlier version.

The `composer.json` MUST NOT have a version. That's what repository tags are for.

Note: The `"type":"vcs"` works generally well and will detect Git, Hg, or SVN repos.

Comment: I have tried this. With `"type":"vcs"`, I get the error `[InvalidArgumentException]                                                                       
  No driver found to handle VCS repository bitbucket.org/my-user/my-private-repo`. With `"type":"hg"`, I get `[Composer\Repository\InvalidRepositoryException]                                                                                                    
  No valid composer.json was found in any branch or tag of bitbucket.org/my-user/my-private-repo, could not load a package from it.` Any thoughts on how I can get around those errors?

Comment: Okay, after hours of beating my head against a wall, I figured it out. The solution was driven by [this page in the Atlassian documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/configure-multiple-ssh-identities-for-gitbash-mac-osx-linux-271943168.html). I had to change your JSON snippet to the following: `"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "hg",
            "url":  "ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/my-user/my-private-repo/"
        }
    ]`, and then it worked. If you will incorporate this in your answer, I'll give you the check mark for steering me down the right road.

Comment: That surprises me as well, thanks for reporting it back. "vcs" is supposed to be autodetection for the repository type, but somehow this fails here.

Comment: Actually, `"type":"vcs"` does seem to work once I fixed the URL. Apparently, it was just the URL format that was the problem.

Comment: I tweaked your edit just slightly in light of my last comment. Thanks for the help!

Comment: `No valid composer.json was found in any branch or tag of ssh://hg@bitbucket  
  .org/foo/bar could not load a package from it.`

Comment: Nevermind, an error like I had just means you either need to run `composer init` or you have a misplaced comma / syntax error in the other repo